# Open jquery modal on Success AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to alert the user that their action is successful when they click the button, here is my code. Please Help. Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function postck3() {
    $.post('insert_home.php', {
      INSERT_WELCOME: CKEDITOR.instances.CKWELCOME.getData()
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where's the issue? Gib me de codez is not a legitimate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$.post('insert_home.php',{INSERT_WELCOME:editor_data3}).done(function(data){
  alert("Success data return ed from server is "+ data);
});
```